# Extract specific values from JSON Array php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a JSON Array

```
    [0] => Array
    (   
        [stage_id] => 80    
        [yieldVal] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [datajson] => [{"name":"doi","value":"215"},{"name":"dateofpollinationstops","value":"Date of Pollination Stops~23-3-2015"}]
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [datajson] => [{"name":"doi","value":"698"},{"name":"dateofpollinationstops","value":"Date of Pollination Stops~23-3-2015"}]
                    )
            )
    )
```

I need to extract the values from this Array

```
    [0] => Array
    (   
        [stage_id] => 80    
        [yieldVal] => Array
            (
                [doi_value] => 215  
                [doi_value] => 698  
            )
    )
```

I have tried decoding the JSON. But unable to continue further.

```
$phpArray = json_decode($res['datajson'], true);
```

How to extract the values and assign the key.

EDIT :  My final output should be

```
[0] => Array
    (   
        [stage_id] => 80    
        [yieldVal] => 913  //215+698  -> Extracting values from [datajson]
    )
```

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($phpArray);`?

Comment: You can't have multiple elements with the same key `doi_value` in an array.

Comment: @D4V1D its showing null..

Comment: Infact i need to sum those values @Barmar

Comment: So you don't want an array in the resulting `yieldVal`? Please update the question to show what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that may of tripped you up is that your `datajson` string is:

```
`[{"name":"doi","value":"215"},{"name":"dateofpollinationstops","value":"Date of Pollination Stops~23-3-2015"}]`
```

The square brackets mean that `json_decode` will create an array from the objects.

Anyway, try this...should give you the exact output you asked for:

```
$yieldVal = 0;

foreach ($res['yieldVal'] as $key => $arr) {

    $decode = json_decode($arr['datajson']);
    $yieldVal = $yieldVal + $decode[0]->value;

}

$newArray = array (

    'stage_id' => $res['stage_id'],
    'yieldVal' => $yieldVal

);

//var_dump($newArray);
echo "<pre>".print_r($newArray, true)."</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get the value with:

```
$doi_value = $phpArray[0]['value'];
```

You can then sum them, push them onto a resulting array, or whatever.